# How to give java arraylist to javascript function using JSON

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, arraylist

I have a table which is created through javascript function which is as below

[image]

Now you can see the cell "VAT5.5" is empty.there i have to get the database values from SQL database and i have to keep those in a dropdown box.I am able to get the database values and store it in an arraylist.But the problem i am facing is to export that arraylist to the javascript function.I heard we can pass the arraylist values to the script function through JSON.So i tried to parse and sent those to javascript function but i didnt know the JSON code properly.So i am facing an error.

My code is as follows

```
<script language="javascript">
                    // Add row to the HTML table


                    function addRow() {    
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
                        var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            


                        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

                        var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
                        element7.setAttribute('multiple', '');
                        var optarr = document.getElementById('data').value;

                        for(var i = 0;i<optarr.length;i++)
                        { 
                         var opt = document.createElement("option");
                         opt.text = optarr[i];

                         opt.value = optarr[i];
                         opt.className = optarr[i];
                         element7.appendChild(opt);
                        } 


                       element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
                       element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
                       element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');

                       cell7.appendChild(element7);

                    }  
<%
            Connection con = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
            String taxgroup;


            try {
                 DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
                 con = db.getCon();
                 String sql = "select distinct TaxGroup from marketing_database.tax_info";
                 PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                 rs = smt.executeQuery();

                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                     taxgroup=rs.getString(1);

                        ar.add(taxgroup);
                        System.out.println("Array is" +ar);
                 }
                 int size = ar.size();


                 System.out.println("size is" +size);

            %>
            <%
            con.close();
            smt.close();
            rs.close();

            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }

            %>
```

So how to get the above arralist to a javascript function.I hope i will get some help

Comment: you've to tell us what is 'username' in the code you've written. I would suggest you read about JSON before start using it inn ur code. Also, please ask specific question with sample code of what you tried not the entire irrelevant code base, In this case  show only a code fragment showing what you want us to help with.eg try would be converting ur ArrayList to JSON String, and use JSON.parse() to get Javascript object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
            Connection con = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
            String taxgroup;


            try {
                 DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
                 con = db.getCon();
                 String sql = "select distinct TaxGroup from marketing_database.tax_info";
                 PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                 rs = smt.executeQuery();

                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                     taxgroup=rs.getString(1);

                        ar.add(taxgroup);
                        System.out.println("Array is" +ar);
                 }
                 int size = ar.size();


                 System.out.println("size is" +size);

            %>
            <%
            con.close();
            smt.close();
            rs.close();

            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }

            %>

 var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

          var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
          element7.setAttribute('multiple', '');
          var jsArray = [];
          <%for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++){%>
              jsArray.push("<%= ar.get(i)%>");
          <%}%>


         //   var optarr =  ["vat1","vat2","vat3","vat4","vat5","vat6","vat7","vat8","vat9"];
          alert(jsArray.length);
          alert(jsArray);
          for(var i = 0;i<jsArray.length;i++)
          { 
           var opt = document.createElement("option");
           opt.text = jsArray[i];

           opt.value = jsArray[i];
           opt.className = jsArray[i];
           element7.appendChild(opt);
          } 
element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
         element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
         element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');

         cell7.appendChild(element7);
```

Comment: Appreciate you tried yourself, +1 , you can modify your code removing the scriptlets.